# Create item is SharePoint with current login user csom

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, csom

I have a web-service, in which authentication mechanism is set to windows(NTLM) authentication. From this web service i am creating/updating items in a SharePoint list. I want to create/update item with current logged-in user. Below is my code block.

```
public string InsertItem(string title)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
            ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "NTLM");
            string siteUrl = "http://spdev:91";
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            clientContext.Credentials = credential;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            List testlist = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem newItem = testlist.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            newItem["Title"] = title;
            newItem.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  
            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }        
    }
```

But everytime item is created by App Pool user instead of logged in user. Is there a way to create items in list with current logged user with code? Appreciate any suggestion in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultNetworkCredentials means that the web service will run under the current security context which is the App Pool. It is also not possible to pass the user credentials.

If your App Pool account has sufficient privileges(Full control over the list/site), then you can set the Created, Created By, Modified and Modified By fields using CSOM. You can pass the current user details(login name) when you invoke the web service

```
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://site");
        List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List");
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
        ctx.Load(items);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        User currentUser= ctx.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\user");
        ctx.Load(currentUser);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item["Created"] = "date";
            item["Modified"] = "date";
            item["Editor"] = currentUser;
            item["Author"] = currentUser;
            item.Update();
        }
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```